Omniauth "Undefined method '[ ]' for an instance of Rack::Request" error
I am learning Ruby on Rails and have been following a tutorial for building a Tweet Scheduler to learn the basics (here). I have made it to OmniAuth 2.0 urls, but aftering navigating to twitter, authorizing, and being redirected back to my app, I get the NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for an instance of Rack::Request.
The error originates from this code, which I can only assume is part of omniauth since its not present anywhere in my app.
opts = {}
if session["oauth"][name.to_s]["callback_confirmed"]
  opts[:oauth_verifier] = request["oauth_verifier"]
else
  opts[:oauth_callback] = callback_url
end

I've tried updating all of my gems

Please update the question with all gem versions and ruby version. Also share the complete backtrace and the last line of your code that appears in it.

Seems like it is a known issue: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/issues/1135

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
